# $index giving error on Empty array Angular

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have the following:

```
<table id="myid" class="class2" style="width: 100%;" >
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="row in detailCollection.Info"  >

            <td>
                <a class="button " ng-click="fire({{$index}})" ng-show="!ViewMode">Upload</a><input ng-show="false" name="{{'fileSocialUpload' + $index}}" id="{{'fileSocialUpload'+ $index}}" onchange="angular.element(this).scope().setFiles(this)" class="file" type="file"/></td>                     

        </tr>                    
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And when the array is empty the ngrepeat seems to be evaluation the `$index` so it throws and error. How to avoid this `$index` evaluation when array is empty on the ngrepeat?

Comment: I solved the one within the ng-click i just removed the {{}} but now is erroring when trying to build the control name based on the index

Comment: Hmm for the name try   name="{{fileSocialUpload}}+ $index"

Comment: No if the array is empty, `ng-repeat` will not read nor write anything at all. Make sure your array is actually empty by `console.log($scope.detailCollection.Info)` and you may have a surprise.

Comment: As a side note, `ng-click="fire({{$index}})"` doesn't make sense, instead you want `ng-click="fire($index)"`, that probably explain your error

Answer (score 0):

Your `name` attribute you are trying to generate with the `$index` is slightly wrong.

Assuming you are trying to generate the name `fileSocialUpload1` for the first element, your syntax should change to:

```
name="fileSocialUpload{{$index}}"
```

This can also be applied to how you are generating your elements `id` attribute value.

```
id="fileSocialUpdate{{$index}}"
```

Syntax inside the `{{}}` isn't normal JS so not all expressions will evaluate the way you might want them to.

Also your use of the `onchange` element could be easier to read.

```
onchange="angular.element(this).scope().setFiles(this)"
```

Can be changed to

```
ng-change="setFiles($index)"
```

Avoiding use of `.scope` to get the scope of an element from the DOM will avoid problems if you move start using directives with isolated scopes or move the `onchange` attribute to another element.

Knowing how the `id` is generated you can select the element within the `setFiles` function using jQuery selector and the passed in `$index` value.

Likewise for the `ng-click`, you want to pass in the `$index` argument, this doesn't have to be evaluated with `{{}}` to pass into an `ng-click`.

Comment: is not the name property that is giving me the error is the id. I made the change suggested, but still is giving me and error

Comment: @GiovanniRivas same principle applies. I'll update my answer. Your solution is more complicated than it needs to be in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

I find the workaround using `ng-attr-id="{{ 'fileSocialUpload' + $index }}"`